# Using Asp button in jquery dialog

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dialog

I have a problem in my code when I'm using an Asp button in a jquery dialog where modal is set to "true".

Here is my code :

Js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var dlg = $("#mws-jui-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Delete",
    modal: true,
    width: "640",
    minHeight : 160,
    minWidth : 170
});
dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form"));

$("#btnDelete").bind("click", function (event) {
    $("#mws-jui-dialog").dialog("option", { modal: true}).dialog("open");
    event.preventDefault();
});
$("#btnClose").bind("click", function (event) {
    $("#mws-jui-dialog").dialog("close");
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

On my aspx page :

```
asp:Button runat="server" ID="bidon" CssClass="mws-button green" OnClick="DeleteButton_Click" Text="Yes"
```

And on my cs :

```
protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.Redirect("mypage.aspx");
}
```

When i set modal to false it's working fine but as i've understood that modal disable items on my page, i'm looking for a way to use my asp button when modal is at true (or just a another way to fix it).

Comment: You are incorrectly referring to you button... it should be referred as $('.mws-button green') instead of $('#mws-button green'). Kindly correct.

Comment: I've tried this but still have the same problem, any ideas ?

Comment: Can you post the markup from `#mws-jui-dialog`?

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is a few months old but if I understand it correctly... In your `mws-button green` CSS class. Include the `z-index:` property and set it too `1000`. This will ensure that your button sits on top of the modal bkgd.

```
.mws-button green
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Let me know if this helps.